# Firefox works but PhantomJS throws Unable to find element with css selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, datepicker, phantomjs

I recently changed from `webdriver.Firefox()` to `webdriver.PhantomJS()` to get a speed improvement and i started getting some errors when i try to find an element on my datepicker in order to click it after

```
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    self.driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a"
            ).click()

Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with css selector '#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"146","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:54784","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"value\": \"#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a\", \"sessionId\": \"8b584560-6eb6-11e6-bb4a-77906b62d5cb\", \"using\": \"css selector\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8b584560-6eb6-11e6-bb4a-77906b62d5cb/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

I am using `selenium==2.53.6` and `phantomjs==2.1.12`

UPDATE (here is the code):

```
def get_price(self, url):
    url = "https://www.homeaway.pt/arrendamento-ferias/p1823902"
    # Lets reset it
    self.driver.get(url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)

    prices = defaultdict(list)

    count = 0
    for month in range(self.month_count):
        next_month_iteration = False
        checkin_date = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    ".quotebar-container input[id=startDateInput]"
                )
            )
        )
        checkin_date.click()

        for counting in range(count):
            try:
                self.driver.execute_script(
                    '$( "a.ui-datepicker-next" ).click()'
                )
            except WebDriverException:
                log.error(
                    'WebDriverException: Message: '
                    'getAvailabilityIndexForDate requires a Date object'
                )
                next_month_iteration = True
                break

        if next_month_iteration:
            # Skip the next iteration cause there was an error
            continue

        year = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            ".ui-datepicker-year").text

        current_month = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            ".ui-datepicker-month").text

        log.info(
            'Current Month is "%s"',
            current_month.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        )

        try:
            first_available_checkin_date = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (
                        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-changeover > a"
                    )
                )
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            log.warning('Is there any date available here "%s" ?', url)
            continue
        else:
            log.info(
                'First_available_checkin_date is "%s"',
                first_available_checkin_date.text
            )
            ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(
                first_available_checkin_date).perform()

            # self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            #     "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a"
            # ).click()

            choose_date = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (
                        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a"
                    )
                )
            )
            choose_date.click()
```

Any ideas how i can fix this??

Comment: Yeah, with PhantomJS you would probably have more cases like this which need to be powered by additional waits, scrolling into views of elements and other "tricks". Have you tried waiting for this element to be present? Thanks.

Comment: hi @alecxe .. if i wait for it i get the same error :( .. any other ideas??

Comment: Difficult to tell, can you post the complete code up until this problematic point? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe yes, edited my question and added the code up until the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your issue and was able to fix it by *maximizing the browser window*:

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: thanks again @alecxe . i had tried the maximize_window before but it wasn't working (maybe i didn't have the waits yet)